# Compare two dates in ASP calender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a noob at ASP, I am trying to take take a selected date from an ASP calendar and save that in a textbox or something that I can compare with the second selected date so that the second is larger. I'm not sure if it is possible while just using one calendar. I tried but do not know how to save the first date collection for comparison. I tried both ways but failed miserable. I did do a search but they are using javascript, or java and other languages I do not know.

**What I want to do:**
I am trying to take two separate inputted dates from user. when 1st date is inputted, store in something, then validate that the user selects a date after the 1st selected date. If not return error message

```
<asp:TextBox ID="response" runat="server" />                       
                                <asp:TextBox ID="caldate1" runat="server" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="caldate2" runat="server" />

                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="calvalidae" runat="server" ControlToCompare="caldate1" ErrorMessage="Date should be later than first date" Type="Date" operator="GreaterThan" ValueToCompare="caldate2"></asp:CompareValidator>
                                <asp:Calendar ID="cal1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
                                <asp:Calendar ID="cal2" runat="server" SelectionMode="Day" OnSelectionChanged="cal1_SelectionChanged" ></asp:Calendar>
```

//serverside

```
protected void cal1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        caldate1.Text = cal1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        if (cal1.SelectedDate.Date > cal2.SelectedDate.Date)
        {
            caldate1.Text = "You selected ";
            caldate1.Text += cal1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        }
        else
        {
            caldate1.Text = "Select a valid date";
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am having hard time in understanding the question. Can you please be more clear? 
What are you trying to achieve?
What is happening with current code?

Comment: Currently, nothing. I am trying to take two seperate inputed dates from user. when 1st date is inputted, store in something, then validate that the user selects a date after the 1st selected date. If not return error message

Comment: When you say nothing, You dont see breakpoints hitting or application not working?

Comment: I was getting an error with the compareValidator so I took that out. The page runs but when i select a date the textbox responds with "select a date"

Comment: Certainly your event name has issues. And your compare validator  is also wrong. Please start looking there to modify to your objectives. Doesn't look like logically right to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to compare the dates in code behind do the below

**Markup**

```
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="calvalidae" runat="server" 
                                  ControlToValidate ="caldate1"  ValueToCompare="text" ControlToCompare="caldate2"
                ErrorMessage="Date should be later than first date" Type="Date" 
                operator="GreaterThan" ></asp:CompareValidator><br/>                      
            <asp:Calendar ID="cal1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="cal1_SelectionChanged1"></asp:Calendar><br/>                      
            <asp:Calendar ID="cal2" runat="server" SelectionMode="Day" OnSelectionChanged="cal2_SelectionChanged" ></asp:Calendar><br/>                      
        </div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    protected void cal1_SelectionChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        caldate1.Text = cal1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        IsValidDate();
    }

    protected void cal2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        caldate2.Text = cal2.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        IsValidDate();
    }


    private void IsValidDate()
    {
        response.Text = string.Empty;
        if (cal1.SelectedDate > cal2.SelectedDate)
        {
            response.Text = "Date should be later than first date";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I literally just did something similar to this and it worked. Is there anyway to do it using 1 calendar or must you use 2 calendars and compare them to each other?

Comment: You may toggle the text based on the text box it has got focus in